# Bigger misc-fixed fonts

Tags: terminal, xterm

I really like look of the 'misc' font family on my laptop.

I use the biggest one available: Misc-Fixed-Medium-R-Normal--20-200-75-75-C-100-ISO10646-1.

However, my desktop PC has an UHD display and this font is totally unreadable. Are there any fixed-style fonts that are approximately 1.5 times larger than that one, or is there a viable way to resize them?

Please don't recommend Terminus as I don't want to use that font.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which distro? In my Ubuntu, I can select hundreds of fonts and only in rare cases can it happen that none fulfills what I want.

Comment: I'm using Deban. I want to use fixed fonts cause they look the best for me. However the biggest misc font size is 10x20 which is too small for me.

Comment: There are monospaced fonts from rpm `dejavu-sans-mono-fonts` or presumably package `fonts-dejavu-core` which allow you to do e.g.  `xterm -fa 'mono:normal:size=60'` for huge fonts.

Comment: [Here](http://www.ru.j-npcs.org/usoft/WWW/HOWTO/mini/X-Big-Cursor) is a description how to resize a cursor font with `bdfresize`; you can do the same for `misc-fixed`. If it works, write the steps as an answer, and accept it.

Comment: Yes, that worked, but is there any version of bdfedit that can scale by float value (e.g. 1.5)? 2 is too big and smaller fonts looks bad. I will write steps soon.

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 16.04. I ran "xlsfonts" and tried some of the fonts whose name ends with "24". I found a font named "b24", a fixed-width font that looks very good in xterm.

It is a pity that there is no decent documentation of what each font means, so I had to use trial and error...

Answer (score 0):

Offhand (looking at the results from `xlsfonts` on my local machine), the adobe-courier has some larger fonts, though some people dislike its appearance:

```
-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--34-240-100-100-m-200-iso10646-1
```

You could also use the "unscaled" tweak in your font configuration, with the caveat that scaled bitmap fonts don't look as good as the originals.

Further reading:

- [Fonts in X11R7.5](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/fonts/fonts.html), which mentions **`:unscaled`** (not much detail, but documentation is not a forte of Xorg...)

Comment: Thanks, however i'm fairly new to Linux and can't figure out how to make it working? Isn't there any way/tool to just scale font bitmaps?

Comment: @whatever15 *bitmaps*, by definition, can't nicely be scaled.  It's why outline fonts were created.  (Yes, I know this is six years old.)